# Is there a way to reference multiple Azure Storage accounts with different prefixes?

Tags: azure, imageresizer

I would like to access different Azure storage account depending on the prefix passed into my application. I fairly sure this is not possible, but just wanted to check.

Thanks!

Richard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's absolutely possible - like nearly all ImageResizer plugins, you can have multiple instances installed, each with their own prefix and credentials.